# Is the dataChanged signal of a QAbstractItemModel also fired for changes of its children?

Tags: c++, qt, signals

For example, if I resize the children in a `QAbstractItemModel`, is it enough to just emit a `dataChanged` signal for the parent index, or should I emit a signal for every child?

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, it is not enough to just emit a dataChanged signal for the parent index.